# Jmeter sample code

Tags: java, jmeter

Need to test the application but I am getting below error:

```
ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: setEndTime must be called after setStartTime java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.setEndTime(SampleResult.java:1023)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1062)
    at infy.dop.rsi.jmeter.EmoDb.runTest(EmoDb.java:94)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:191)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

He is my code:

```
public class EmoDb extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmoDb.class);
    private Properties prop = new Properties();
    public Arguments getDefaultParameters() {
        Arguments defaultParameters = new Arguments();
        return defaultParameters;
    }
    public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
        for (Iterator<String> it = context.getParameterNamesIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String paramName = it.next();
            prop.put(paramName, context.getParameter(paramName));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0) {
        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
        try {
            URL url=new URL(" ");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();
            result.sampleStart();
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (code==200)
            {
                System.out.println("OK");
                result.sampleEnd();
            }
             else {
                throw new Exception("status is not=200");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            result.sampleEnd();
            result.setSuccessful(false);
            result.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
            result.setSampleLabel(e.getMessage());
            return result;
        }
        result.setSuccessful(true);
        result.setResponseMessage("Successfully completed");
        result.setResponseOK();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's at `SampleResult.java:1023`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got any exception in the block:

```
    URL url=new URL(" ");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();
```

The catch-block is called. There you call

```
result.sampleEnd();
```

But

```
result.sampleStart();
```

is not called, because of the exception.

Comment: .I intensely removed url in this code.I am using actually in my system since I am not  supposed to expose the url so i did.

Comment: @user3619264 Do not male it blank. add a pseudo URL like http://example.com

Comment: @user3619264 you are sure that you not get any exception before `result.sampleStart();`

Comment: Actually jens the same code is working fine for other url but for particular url which I need to do PT test I am facing the issue.

Comment: You get an Output from this line: LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));?

Comment: I removed and tried but no luck.. still facing same error:(

Comment: @user3619264 What have you removed?

Comment: Do you really need to write code ? Why didn't you use JMeter with the GUI ? It should be much more easier ! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_quick_guide.htm

Comment: I removed  LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e))

Comment: @user3619264 you should not remove this line. I would know if you get an Output from this logstatement if yes what is the root cause

Comment: I was checking the jmeter.log file in which the above error got.Just now I checked the app log i got the correct error:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Comment: @user3619264 So your URL is not reachable, the catch block is called and there you set sampleEnd()