# Jmeter - gRPC : java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence

Tags: jmeter, grpc

We are working on the gRPC protocol; everything went well while attempting to execute via Postman but we are unable to execute via Jmeter and encountered the following problem.

```
2022-07-11 15:47:18,322 ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult: setEndTime must be called after setStartTime
java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.setEndTime(SampleResult.java:1107) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1145) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.errorResult(GRPCSampler.java:112) [jmeter-grpc-request-v1.2.1.jar:?]
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.sample(GRPCSampler.java:79) [jmeter-grpc-request-v1.2.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_321]
2022-07-11 15:47:18,322 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'GRPC Request'.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.errorResult(GRPCSampler.java:114) ~[jmeter-grpc-request-v1.2.1.jar:?]
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.sample(GRPCSampler.java:79) ~[jmeter-grpc-request-v1.2.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
```

[A snapshot of the error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKcFA.jpg)

Comment: Probably we will need to see a [mcve] to help you, specifically code that reproduces the problem.  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.  Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  You might also [edit] your question to tag it with the language and framework(s) you are using as this increases the chance of attracting the attention of an expert.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging.

Comment: Did you look for questions containing *`SampleResult: setEndTime must be called after setStartTime`*?  I found [Jmeter sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39483527) and [setEndTime must be called after setStartTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51892501).  Do either of those answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're suffering from [this bug](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request/issues/96), according to the [comment](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request/issues/96#issuecomment-1178601750) the fix has been submitted 4 days ago

Try updating the plugin to the most recent version using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager) or building the plugin from the [source](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-request) using [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and the error should go away or you should see more meaningful response.